# Python Convertir string en a base64

Tags: python, xml

En python, Obtengo el valor de una etiqueta de un archivo xml. En este caso obtengo el valor de la etiqueta X509Certificate, ahora este valor quiero convertirlo a un string base64 para luego procesarlo a una imagen.

```
<ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
```

Este el valor de la etiqueta xml X509Certificate

Comment: Hola J_JS ¿Cuál es el problema exactamente? Mírate https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html

Comment: Estoy procesando un archivo xml que son datos de una factura electronica, los datos lo almaceno a la base de datos, luego desde jasper report obtener esos valores para generar el reporte. Como puedo generar la imagen qr en el reporte?

Comment: @J_JS muestra lo que has intentado, Lee lo siguiente para mejorar tu pregunta:  [ask]